# want to execute this whole as a single command

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM ((SELECT * FROM `board` WHERE name LIKE '%read%'
 OR groups LIKE '%read%'
 OR years LIKE '%read%'
 OR memo LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c0 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `campusold` WHERE article LIKE '%read%'
 OR date LIKE '%read%'
 OR volume LIKE '%read%'
 OR issue LIKE '%read%'
 OR page LIKE '%read%'
 OR reporter LIKE '%read%'
 OR office1 LIKE '%read%'
 OR office2 LIKE '%read%'
 OR subject1 LIKE '%read%'
 OR subject2 LIKE '%read%'
 OR person1 LIKE '%read%'
 OR person2 LIKE '%read%'
 OR person3 LIKE '%read%'
 OR memo LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c1 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `campusreportauthority` WHERE CampusReportID LIKE '%read%'
 OR CampusReportSubjectID LIKE '%read%'
 OR PhotoIncluded LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c2 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `campusreportmain` WHERE CampusReportID LIKE '%read%'
 OR Title LIKE '%read%'
 OR DocumentTypeID LIKE '%read%'
 OR ContentNoteID LIKE '%read%'
 OR IssueID LIKE '%read%'
 OR Page LIKE '%read%'
 OR Notes LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c3 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `campusreportpersons` WHERE CampusReportID LIKE '%read%'
 OR CampusReportPersonID LIKE '%read%'
 OR PhotoIncluded LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c4 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `campusreportreporters` WHERE CampusReportID LIKE '%read%'
 OR CampusReportReporterID LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c5 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `collectioninformation` WHERE CollectionName LIKE '%read%'
 OR Creator LIKE '%read%'
 OR Language LIKE '%read%'
 OR Format LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c6 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `contentnotes` WHERE ContentID LIKE '%read%'
 OR Letter LIKE '%read%'
 OR Details LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c7 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `controlledvocabulary` WHERE ControlledVocabulary# LIKE '%read%'
 OR ControlledVocabulary LIKE '%read%'
 OR Notes LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c8 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `cvsegment` WHERE CVSegmentID LIKE '%read%'
 OR CVRecordid LIKE '%read%'
 OR ControlledVocabularyid LIKE '%read%'
 OR CVRunningTime LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c9 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `documenttype` WHERE DocumentTypeID LIKE '%read%'
 OR DocumentType LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c10 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `faculty` WHERE name LIKE '%read%'
 OR department LIKE '%read%'
 OR years LIKE '%read%'
 OR memo LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c11 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `flyernewsauthority` WHERE FlyerNewsID LIKE '%read%'
 OR FNSubjectID LIKE '%read%'
 OR PhotoIncluded LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c12 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `flyernewsmain` WHERE FlyerID LIKE '%read%'
 OR Title LIKE '%read%'
 OR DocumentTypeID LIKE '%read%'
 OR ContentNoteID LIKE '%read%'
 OR IssueID LIKE '%read%'
 OR Page LIKE '%read%'
 OR Notes LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c13 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `flyernewspersons` WHERE FlyerNewsID LIKE '%read%'
 OR FNPersonID LIKE '%read%'
 OR Photoincluded LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c14 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `flyernewsthrough2004` WHERE article LIKE '%read%'
 OR date LIKE '%read%'
 OR volume LIKE '%read%'
 OR issue LIKE '%read%'
 OR page LIKE '%read%'
 OR reporter LIKE '%read%'
 OR office1 LIKE '%read%'
 OR office2 LIKE '%read%'
 OR subject1 LIKE '%read%'
 OR subject2 LIKE '%read%'
 OR person1 LIKE '%read%'
 OR person2 LIKE '%read%'
 OR person3 LIKE '%read%'
 OR memo LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c15 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `issuewithid` WHERE IssueID LIKE '%read%'
 OR Date LIKE '%read%'
 OR Volume LIKE '%read%'
 OR Issue LIKE '%read%'
 OR Note LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c16 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `junkmain` WHERE FlyerID LIKE '%read%'
 OR person3 LIKE '%read%'
 OR memo LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c17 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `keywords` WHERE Keyword# LIKE '%read%'
 OR Keyword LIKE '%read%'
 OR Notes LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c18 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `keywordsegment` WHERE KeywordSegmentid LIKE '%read%'
 OR KeywordRecordid LIKE '%read%'
 OR Keywordid LIKE '%read%'
 OR KeywordRunningTime LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c19 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `msyscompacterror` WHERE ErrorCode LIKE '%read%'
 OR ErrorDescription LIKE '%read%'
 OR ErrorRecid LIKE '%read%'
 OR ErrorTable LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c20 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `originalformatandtechnicalinformation` WHERE Recordid LIKE '%read%'
 OR OriginalBoxNumber LIKE '%read%'
 OR OriginalFormat LIKE '%read%'
 OR SourceCode LIKE '%read%'
 OR TechnicalNotes LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c21 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `rights` WHERE Rightsid LIKE '%read%'
 OR RightsCode LIKE '%read%'
 OR Name LIKE '%read%'
 OR Notes LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c22 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `rightsdescription` WHERE RightsCode LIKE '%read%'
 OR RightsVerbiage LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c23 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `ua_latitudes_longitudes_buildings` WHERE Roesch_Library LIKE '%read%'
 OR Column_39_74021 LIKE '%read%'
 OR Column_84_1788 LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c24 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `ua_ud_buildings` WHERE Albert_Emanual_Hall LIKE '%read%'
 OR Column_2 LIKE '%read%'
 OR Column_3 LIKE '%read%'
 OR Column_1928 LIKE '%read%'
 OR Yes LIKE '%read%'
 OR Column_1999 LIKE '%read%'
 OR Column_7 LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c25 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `walterscollection` WHERE Recordid LIKE '%read%'
 OR Title LIKE '%read%'
 OR DVCid LIKE '%read%'
 OR Date LIKE '%read%'
 OR CoverageDates LIKE '%read%'
 OR RunningTime LIKE '%read%'
 OR Description LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c26 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `waltersinccollection` WHERE Recordid LIKE '%read%'
 OR Title LIKE '%read%'
 OR Rights LIKE '%read%'
 OR DVCNumber LIKE '%read%'
 OR Date LIKE '%read%'
 OR Coveragedates LIKE '%read%'
 OR RunningTime LIKE '%read%'
 OR Description LIKE '%read%'
 OR Blank LIKE '%read%'
 OR Originalboxnumber LIKE '%read%'
 OR Originalformat LIKE '%read%'
 OR SourceCode LIKE '%read%'
 OR Technicalnotes LIKE '%read%'
 OR Blank2 LIKE '%read%'
 OR Keywords LIKE '%read%'
 OR ControlledVocabulary LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3) AS c27) As wholesql
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS c1 UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `campusreportauthority` WHERE CampusReportID LIKE '%' at line 18

i was getting many errors from initial stage, like using alias for every derived tables which was the previous one, so i kept alias for all the statements. but not able to find what this error is

Comment: This will never work: you cannot run a `UNION` between tables with different number of columns.

**What is it** that you're trying to do (apart from running a lot of table scans) and in which language? Try asking *that* in a new question.

Comment: i am trying to search for a keyword in a database with different tables in php, i first run every query in a loop which gives me so many results around 600 plus which when i try to change dom for every result, the app crashes. so i wanted to implement pagination for sending for selecting 10 results in a query initially and change according to page number. but as i run queries in a loop i cant exactly know  where to stop and start according to pagenumber. so ive been trying to run that in a single command, which i think is not going to work now.

Comment: This is a complex request. I think I might have some insights - for pagination, too - but I'd advise you to make your comment, and this question, into a new question (something like "Wide search on a range of tables"), specifying the PHP tag, as *this* question is very close to being off topics and is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing with the first unions but the spirit remains the same,
You dont need to alias the queries in you union.
Do this for example
;

```
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `board` WHERE name LIKE '%read%'
     OR groups LIKE '%read%'
     OR years LIKE '%read%'
     OR memo LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3 UNION 
    SELECT * FROM `campusold` WHERE article LIKE '%read%'
     OR date LIKE '%read%'
     OR volume LIKE '%read%'
     OR issue LIKE '%read%'
     OR page LIKE '%read%'
     OR reporter LIKE '%read%'
     OR office1 LIKE '%read%'
     OR office2 LIKE '%read%'
     OR subject1 LIKE '%read%'
     OR subject2 LIKE '%read%'
     OR person1 LIKE '%read%'
     OR person2 LIKE '%read%'
     OR person3 LIKE '%read%'
     OR memo LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3 UNION 
    SELECT * FROM `campusreportauthority` WHERE CampusReportID LIKE '%read%'
     OR CampusReportSubjectID LIKE '%read%'
     OR PhotoIncluded LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3 

... other unions
```

Comment: Thats how i started and i get the following error. Incorrect usage of union and limit

Comment: then i looked for a solution online, and kept paranthesis around each query which led  to alias error.

Comment: Only the last one is necessary: OR ControlledVocabulary LIKE '%read%' LIMIT 0, 3 ) As wholesql

Comment: You need also to make sure all queries unioned have the same count of columns

Comment: soory i dont know that, they have different number of columns and names as well.